# p-inputMask ng-model not clearing for invalid value

Tags: angular, primeng, input-mask

I am using `inputMask` field from PrimeNG

```
<p-inputMask name="maskValue" [(ngModel)]="attr.attributeValue" mask="aa/99" placeholder="aa/99"></p-inputMask>

{{attr.attributeValue}}
```

But if I enter `a` in the textbox and focus out, that textbox is clearing but ng-model `attr.attributeValue` is still hold value `a_/__`. How could we clear the ng-model as well ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By looking to the [source of inputMask](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/src/app/components/inputmask/inputmask.ts#L106), you can see that there is a boolean property called `filled`.

So we can access the value of that property to know if the input is filled or not through `ViewChild` and by using `onBlur` event where you can reinitialize your model if it is not filled.

**HTML**

```
<p-inputMask #myInputMask name="maskValue" [(ngModel)]="attr.attributeValue" mask="aa/99" placeholder="aa/99" (onBlur)="isInputMaskFilled($event)"></p-inputMask>
```

**TS**

```
@ViewChild('myInputMask') myInputMask: InputMask;

isInputMaskFilled(event) {
  if(!this.myInputMask.filled) {
    this.attr = { attributeValue: '' };
  }
}
```

See [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kfupdy)